# How to add custom header when composing mails?

Tags: macos, mail.app

For example, I would like to add the [`In-Reply-To`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4) field myself, because I want to [respond to an archived message](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/reply-to-mailman-archived-message).

Comment: It would be helpful to know what macOS version you have and if you have a preference as to which mail client you would like to do this with. Flexibility on that latter would be good as I don't believe mail.app allows editing headers.

Comment: @SteveChambers I only have Mail.app and Microsoft Outlook installed. I have heard that Thunderbird can do this, but would prefer not to switch at the time. Mail.app can show headers for incoming mails, so I thought it makes sense to allow adding headers for outgoing ones.

Answer (score 2):

## UserHeaders

For Apple's Mail.app, you can use the default `UserHeaders` to provide a dictionary of key value pairs to insert into the headers of outgoing e-mails.

To set the `Disposition-Notification-To` header to `email@address` the following command can be used:

```
 defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist UserHeaders '{"Disposition-Notification-To" = "email@address"; }'
```

On macOS 10.14, you will need to grant Terminal.app the *Full Disk Access* right in **System Preferences.app > Privacy & Security** before issuing the above command.

See [Mail Receipt](https://miln.eu/mailreceipt/) for an example of this default and notes about its application.